# Advantages Creating a viewcontroller in IB vs calling a view controller programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I'm struggling to understand the advantage of using the orange circle view controller in IB over just calling the view controller needed in code.

Thoughts? Opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, let's turn your question around:

> I'm struggling to understand the advantage of calling the view
>   controller needed in code over just using the orange circle view
>   controller in IB.

Any advantage to using/not using IB is purely based on the preference of the coder. If you are more comfortable doing it in code (and find it easier to maintain) then just do that. However, if you are working in a team, it might be better to keep things compartmentalized using IB to allow for easier collaboration. YMMV, and I would encourage you to do whatever makes you more productive.